# Apache server on raspberry pi refuse the incoming connections if it was from iphone or from the flat internet on android

Tags: networking, apache-http-server, android, webserver, iphone

I have a web server installed on RPI 3, it's working great except if the connection is coming from a public wifi, an iPhone device, an Android device if it was using the mobile data/flat internet.

He is telling me that the site can't be reached and the error is ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED and he is taking just the incoming connections from private wifi no matter which kind of device except iPhone

I have Apache running on my raspberry pi

I don't know which info is needed for this question so please ask me for the required info

Answer (score 0):

There could likely be a few potential problems here:

- Your Raspberry Pi might have a firewall that is blocking external connections.
- You haven't set up your router correctly (especially port-forwarding).
- Your ISP is blocking the connection for some reason or uses [Carrier-Grade NAT](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Carrier-grade_NAT).

I would start with the first item and work my way down the list from there.

**Tips**

- `iptables` and `ufw` (which is an interface to `iptables`) are probably the most likely firewall items you might have on the Pi.
- If you are unsure how to set up port-forwarding on your router, the router's manual typically details these steps (i.e. how to route incoming requests from your *external IP:por*t to the *internal IP:port* of your server). Otherwise, you might be able to find steps for your particular device online.
- Some ISPs block ports such as port 80 (the default for HTTP). You should also check that the WAN address assigned to your router is the same as your external IP address (e.g. [as give by Google](https://www.google.com/search?q=what+is+my+IP)).

Comment: well, it receives the coming connections from outside the home. so the first tip isn't logical. The Port forwarding is set because I can connect from outside the home from my android. so the third tip isn't logical too. firewall is already set because I can receive connections so so its not logic as well. So I just need to check the ISP. but I don't think that there is a problem with it. Does the RPI know the command ufw? Because I tried to open the firewall but my RPI didn't know the command ufw!!!!

Comment: My apologies for any incorrect assumptions. `ufw` can be installed on a Pi but it isn't always. If `ufw --version` is not available from the command line, then it almost certainly isn't installed.